# ASP - Randomize function returning same value for two different seeds

Tags: asp-classic

So I'm generating a random number using Rnd and Randomize to set a seed that looks like this:

```
Randomize lSeed
Response.Write Rnd
```

I'm noticing that it's returning the same result for two values in a row for lSeed (e.g. 123, 124) but then on say 125 it will return a new value but 126 will be the same as the on for 125. Why would this be?

Edit:

I have tried something like this

```
Randomize
Randomize lSeed
Response.write Rnd
```

And I get the same results I described above.

Comment: Can you show a more complete repro for this, I'm not getting your results, I get a different behaviour than you are describing.  A single randomize with a fixed seed gets a unique series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the value for the seed was too large in the other environment (an incrementing database value). I ended up doing value Mod 100 to get something semi-random and that was going to be low to always work.

Answer (score 2):

That's the problem with random numbers...

http://web.archive.org/web/20011027002011/http://dilbert.com/comics/dilbert/archive/images/dilbert2001182781025.gif

Answer (score 0):

You should reseed before getting a random value each time. I'd recommend seeding to a timer.

Comment: I tried reseeding. I edited the question above to explain what I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can also seed off of the current time that seems to work pretty well

Comment: I need to sometimes return consistent results so I need to reseed from a value I give it.

Comment: You probably shouldnt use Random numbers if you want consistent results.

Comment: If you provide the same seed you will get the same results from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
' For ASP, you can create a function like:
Public Function RandRange(ByVal low As Integer, ByVal high As Integer) As Integer
    Randomize()
    Return ((Rnd() * (high - low)) + low)
End Function

' For ASP.NET, you can create a function like:
Private _rnd As System.Random()
Public Function RandRange(ByVal low As Integer, ByVal high As Integer) As Integer
    ' Purpose: Returns Random Integer between low and high, inclusive
    ' Note: _rnd variable must be defined outside of RandRange function
    If _rnd Is Nothing Then
        _rnd = New System.Random()
    End If
    Return _rnd.Next(low, high)
End Function
```